# 2D vector to Quaternion

Tags: mathematics, vector, ogre, quaternion

I have a 2D vector (with only X and Y), and my engine only supports orientation through Quaternions.

How do I translate a 2D vector to a quaternion?

The X and Y represent the direction (so X = 0 and Y=1 means going forward, X=0.707 and Y=0.707 means rotate 45 degree, etc).

Comment: What library is it?  Are you sure it doesn't have any interchange methods?

Comment: Ogre3D, and I have no idea what methods to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Ogre3d's docs](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Quaternion.html#ac3328c1bb86d17e870c57d52720e2e32):

```
void Ogre::Quaternion::FromAngleAxis(
    const Radian & rfAngle, const Vector3 & rkAxis )
```

Your `rkAxis` will always be UnitZ, because you are constraining yourself to the X-Y plane.

Comment: and the angle? How do I find it?

Comment: It's the angle of rotation, and it is arbitrary.

Comment: But how do I find the angle from a 2D vector?

Comment: You have some options there, but it will probably involve [arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

Comment: it is better to store the rotation/orientation and calculate the direction from it if possible